# Connecting sidekiq to twemproxy(nutcracker)

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq, twemproxy

I'm trying to connect my sidekiq to a twemproxy instead of a direct Redis connection, but I'm getting the following error:

```
2013-09-30T17:16:53Z 23329 TID-3q3o4 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.12.1 using redis://localhost:22121 with options {}
2013-09-30T17:16:53Z 23329 TID-3q3o4 INFO: Running in ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
2013-09-30T17:16:53Z 23329 TID-3q3o4 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
Connection lost (ECONNRESET)
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `rescue in io'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:206:in `io'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:214:in `read'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `block in call'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:187:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:295:in `ensure_connected'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:177:in `block in process'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:256:in `logging'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:176:in `process'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:410:in `block in keys'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:409:in `keys'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.1/lib/sidekiq/api.rb:71:in `block in cleanup'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/connection_pool-1.1.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:49:in `with'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.1/lib/sidekiq.rb:67:in `redis'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.1/lib/sidekiq/api.rb:70:in `cleanup'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.1/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:55:in `run'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.1/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/mnt/-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

It seems that I'm loosing the connection, but I could not identify what is the root cause. Do you know if it is compatible to try this kind of connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of sidekiq (by the time 2.14.1) is able to connect to twemproxy instead of a redis server.

But due to the use of `brpop` command, it is not compatible.